# Finding a row from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I am trying to write a function `get_value <- function(gyear, gmonth)` that selects a row from already existing dataframe or a value if the month is between two time points. The dataframe is e.g.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
year    month   var1    var2
2022    1       123     987
2021    4       234     876
2021    1       345     765
2020    7       456     654 
2020    3       567     543
2020    1       678     432
2019    1       789     321")
```

For example in year 2021 the same row

```
year    month   var1    var2
2021    1       345     765
```

is valid for months 1,2,3 and then comes a change and the next row

```
year    month   var1    var2
2021    4       234     876
```

is valid for months 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

If the `year` & `month` are already in the dataframe, then I can have the row like

```
get_value <- function(gyear, gmonth){
  library(tidyverse)
  temp <- df %>% filter(year == gyear & month == gmonth)
}

get_value(gyear = 2020, gmonth = 1)
```

but what I want is also to be able to have rows (months) that are between the months that are included in the dataframe. For example I would like to be able to call

```
get_value(gyear = 2021, gmonth = 5)
```

that returns row

```
year    month   var1    var2
2021    4       234     876
```

because in year 2021 the month is between 4-12.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, does my answer work for you? If it did, you could accept it by clicking the check-mark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a new column `month2` to indicate the ending months.

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  arrange(month, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(month2 = lead(month-1, default = 12), .after = month) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#    year month month2 variable1 variable2
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>     <int>     <int>
# 1  2019     1     12       789       321
# 2  2020     1      2       678       432
# 3  2020     3      6       567       543
# 4  2020     7     12       456       654
# 5  2021     1      3       345       765
# 6  2021     4     12       234       876
# 7  2022     1     12       123       987
```

Then customize a filter function that takes a dataframe as input and extract those rows where `gmonth >= month & gmonth <= month2`.

```r
get_value <- function(data, gyear, gmonth){
  data %>%
    filter(year == gyear & gmonth >= month & gmonth <= month2)
}
```

I don't encourage you to put the code where I manipulate `df` to get `month2` into this function. If you do that, the data will be repeatedly manipulated whenever `get_value()` is run. It's out of efficiency.

---

###### Output

```r
get_value(df2, gyear = 2020, gmonth = 1)

# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#    year month month2 variable1 variable2
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>     <int>     <int>
# 1  2020     1      2       678       432
```

```r
get_value(df2, gyear = 2021, gmonth = 5)

# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#    year month month2 variable1 variable2
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>     <int>     <int>
# 1  2021     4     12       234       876
```